# screenbright win7 powershell/commandline alternative

Tags: windows-7, powershell, brightness, powercfg

Work computer, so I cannot install any thirdparty apps :(

Does anyone have the command line samples that work like screenbright?

2 monitors, one is darker than other and OS will brighten/darken BOTH...need ps/cmdline to brighten each monitor seperately.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Reading your question again, it might not work for you, as it looks like you're looking for something to change brightness of each monitor independently.

Try this:

http://timebend.com/bright

It's command line and you don't need to install it. Full disclosure: I wrote it.